# htaccess redirection without base name

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

I am handling some urls with the htaccess like below

```
B)https://www.example.com/online/development/id
```

Rules:

```
RewriteRule ^online/(.*)/(.*)$ filename.php?key=$2 [L]
```

But Now I want to use some urls like below:-

```
https://www.example.com/development/id
```

How Can I do this?

Comment: Try `^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$`

Comment: please remember development is a dynamic word

Comment: In your solution, what will be the base file(file.php) where I need to place the code?

Comment: It is just your regex that should be replaced with mine: `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ filename.php?key=$2 [L]`. `[^/]+` matches 1+ chars other than `/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule-

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)$ filename.php?key=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: what is the use of [\w-]+ here, please explain

Comment: Sorry i can't get you, if for explanation we are matching only two matching group without online in url and then appending the 2nd matching group result into your file.

Comment: I am just asking use of \w- in regex

Comment: [\w-](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html) matches character range {A-Za-z0-9_} with - in the rule.

Comment: Can we use special characters in the url like à, è etc?

Comment: Afaik i don't think we can use special characters like you mentioned but there is a [flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b) for encoding unicode characters. also i think by using ^(.*)$ instead \w- can cover the special characters also.

Comment: I will check, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your regex matches:

- `^` - start of the input (the part after HOST)
- `online/` - the literal char sequence `online/`
- `(.*)` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible, up to the *last*...
- `/` - slash,
- `(.*)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars up to the...
- `$` - end of input.

So, the regex can have arbitrary number of subparts in the path.

If you need to limit the number of subparts, use a *negated character class* based regex:

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]*/([^/]*)$ filename.php?key=$1 [L]
```

The `[^/]+` matches 1+ chars other than `/`. Since you are not using Group 1, I recommend removing the first set of `(` and `)` and use `$1` in the replacement.

Now, the regex matches:

- `^` - start of input
- `[^/]*` - zero or more chars other than `/` (the `[^...]` is called a *negated character class*)
- `/` - a slash
- `([^/]*)` - Group 1: see above
- `$` - end of input.

And that means there can be only 1 slash in the path.